# Join together multiple columns into new one via mapping them through a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to figure out how I can create a new column joining the values of the other columns' corresponding keys... I explain hereafter:

Assume this dictionary and the following dataframe:

```
my_dict={np.nan:0, 'A':10, 'B':22, 'C':23, 'D':50, 'E':7}
my_df=pd.DataFrame({'col_1':['D', 'A', 'C', 'E'], 'col_2':['B', 'A', np.nan, 'C'], 'col_3':['D', 'A', 'E', 'C']})
```

Desired output is:

```
  col_1   col_2   col_3    new_col
0     D       B       D   50-22-50
1     A       A       A   10-10-10
2     C     NaN       E    23-0-10
3     E       C       C    7-23-23
```

Any nice GENERIC ideas, please? I know I can map every column to a new and then join, but I prefer something **more general for really many columns**...

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I believe `replace` and `agg`/`apply`:

```
my_df['new_col'] = my_df.replace(my_dict).astype(str).agg('-'.join, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  col_1 col_2 col_3   new_col
0     D     B     D  50-22-50
1     A     A     A  10-10-10
2     C   NaN     E    23-0-7
3     E     C     C   7-23-23
```

Comment: Very elegant solution!

Comment: @Quang Hoang, it works like a charm! What if the values of my_dict were lists and, say, I wanted the 0th element of each value... how would you code it? Thanks in advance!